# Auto overwrite mode when writing commands in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

In Sublime Text 2 it's possible to toggle overwrite mode with cmd+alt+o, but what I'd really like is to toggle it automatically on commenting, ie. whenever typing "//"

Is it possible without too much fuss?

Comment: This might be little bit related, but not a solution. Check DocBlockr addon which makes writing comments little bit smarter: https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

Comment: What I was looking for was focused on commenting out code, but thank you — it looks useful.

Comment: There is also menu item to convert the selection to commented block and back